# Scala: How to remove a duplicate attribute?

Tags: scala, scalaxb

In scalaxb I have an element with duplicates:

`xsi:type="ObjectEventType" xsi:type="ObjectEventType"`

When duplicates exist how do I traverse the tree and transform to a new tree removing the duplicates?

Comment: Is this a scalaxb specific issue or an xml processing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was [resolved](https://github.com/eed3si9n/scalaxb/issues/95) a while back.

Comment: yes, it was, and thanks as if I remember correctly you fixed it once I posted on your list pretty quickly like the same night(damn good support on that project).  This is a very old question.